# How to get status of the workflow from related the document ? , About Folder Rule Script of Alfresco

Tags: javascript, alfresco, alfresco-share, alfresco-webscripts

I want to move documents between "working folder" to "In Progress folder" 
 according status of workflow when I started our Alfresco's workflow.These Folder was created by me in Sites of Alfresco.

The following code for Folder Rule Script does not work through what I tried. Then, What do you know, How to get status of the workflow from related the document ? I think, want to update script.

```
var parentFolder = document.parent;
var WFstatus = workflow.parameters["bpm:status"];
if (WFstatus.indexOf('In progress') != -1){
    var dest = parentFolder.parent.childByNamePath("2.InProgress");
    document.move(dest);
}
```

Alfresco Version:Community Edition 5.2 & Enterprise 5.2.4

Best regards,

Answer (score 0):

Please confirm, my understanding.

Do you want to move the fils between two folders," Working Folder" to "In progress folder" based on the workflow status correct?

The workflow status can be, either Active (running) and Completed, but the current task can have the status of " In progress".

Here is the Javascript console code, to get the selected document's workflow & task status.

```
//Get the parents for the document node.
//If the document is attached to the workflow, then there will be multiple parents.
for(var x=0;x<document.parents.length;x++)
{
    var t = document.parents[x];
    var workflowNode;
    //Pick the bpm:package node. 
    if (t.type == "{http://www.alfresco.org/model/bpm/1.0}package")
    {
        workflowNode = t;
        logger.log(t);
        //Get the workflow instance Id
        var wfId = t.properties["bpm:workflowInstanceId"];
        logger.log(wfId)

        //get the workflow instance
        var rwf = workflow.getInstance(wfId);
        logger.log(rwf);
        logger.log("Workflow status : " + rwf.active);


        for (var pid in rwf.paths) 
        {
           var path = rwf.paths[pid];
           //Get the tasks and its status
           for (var tid in path.tasks)
           {
             var task = path.tasks[tid];
             logger.log(task);
             logger.log("Task id : "  +  task.id +" task status :" + task.properties["bpm:status"])
           }
         }
    }   

}
print("\n");
print("\n");
print("\n");
print("\n");
```

[image: Sample Code]

As you've got the task status and you should be able to move the file between folders.

Hope this helps you !!